# Update php variable after success ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to change a php variable after success ajax call. How do I do this?

I have a function that update path name directory in database and directory. So, I have a php variable in the beginning of page that's get the path of a file. This is called $final_path.

```
<?php
$path_directory = trim($pathDAO->path_dir($id_pag)[0]->path);
$final_path = trim('http://www.test.com/content/'.$path_directory);
?>
```

I put a hidden div in html:

```
<div id="dir_path" hidden="true"><?php echo $final_path; ?></div>
```

So, when you change the name of directory, I call an ajax function as below.
Notice after success, the php variable should be updated, but it is not happened.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'change_name.php',
    data: {id: uid, name: uname},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
                var data_path = data.split("||");
                var result = $.trim(data_path[0]);
                var result_a = $.trim(data_path[1]);

                if(result === "success") {

                    document.getElementById("dir_path").value = result_a;
                    document.getElementById("dir_path").innerHTML = result_a;

            }
});
return false;
```

In Ajax function, I update the path name and return the result (success or fail) and the new path directory.

```
$success = $updatePath ->update($_POST['id'], $_POST['name']);
$path_directory = trim($pathDAO->path_dir($_POST['id'])[0]->path);

$path_dir = trim('http://www.test.com/content/'.$caminho_diretorio);

$result = $success.'||'.$path_dir;

echo $result;
```

That's work well. But the variable $final_path haven't updated.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean contents of `<div id="dir_path"` don't update, don't you?

Comment: @u_mulder I want to update the value of variable $final_path, and not the content of div.

Comment: Js knows __nothing__ about php variables. If you don't understand that - it's very bad for you.

Comment: I know the javascript is client side and php is server side. But I would like to know if it is possible to change the value of variable after ajax call. I need this!

Comment: PHP runs exactly once, to create the page that is sent to the client.  Then the client runs any JavaScript on the page.  The PHP code no longer exists when the page reaches the client, view source to see this.  The only thing you can do is use AJAX or frames and *re-load* parts of your page by making a separate call to script code on the server that again runs exactly once then sends back a new frame (or AJAX data) to the client page.  Nothing is running on the server when the client is running the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your $final_path variable can't be updated because the execution of the php page is already done at this point. PHP variables are not kept in memory after the server has finished processing the page.

If you need to do further processing on the server-side with this value, then you need to either store it in user-session or keep the value that you got in the resulting ajax call and send it as POST data when you call your next php page.